# JDBC program to create two different connections

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc, oracle-sqldeveloper, jdbc-odbc

Is it possible to select the data from two different database management systems? Suppose I have one table in Oracle Database and other table in mySQL database and If I want to select the data from two different databases is possible? How the JDBC program looks like??

Comment: Of cause its possible. Did you try anything yet? any code?

Comment: "Actually it was my interview question"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need two different Jdbc drivers for oracle and mysql, and set up two separate connections.

Comment: As this correct answer says… A JDBC connection to a database server is just a network connection, like any other. Just as your web browser can open multiple tabs or windows and make connections to multiple web servers, so can your Java app use its JDBC driver(s) to connect to multiple DB servers.

Comment: "Thank you for your answer. Actually I did the same by creating the two separate connections to the two different databases"